# Problem selecting UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: uitableview, cell

I'm new programming in Swift. I have this tableview populated with json data through Alamofire, but I have two problems. I don't know how to add space between cells, the space that I have with my value called "cellSpacingHeight" is an space between sections, but not between cells in the same section.
My other problem is that when I tap a cell, I go to my other View Controller called WorkViewController but always saving the data of the last object of the json data in  vc.zoneName = projects.name. What I really need is to tap a cell and go to WorkViewController with the value of the zoneName associated to the cell that I tapped.
I would really appreciate answers with lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell spacing:

I don't think there is a simple way to set cell spacing, what you can do is increase the cell height using the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` method. For example, if your cell needs to have a height of 100 and a top+bottom margins of 5, you can implement the method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 110
}
```

Then on your cell `ProjectTableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let currentItem = array_item[indexPath.row]
     let dicProject = currentItem as! NSDictionary
     let cellProject = projectsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellProject", for: indexPath) as! ProjectTableViewCell

     // Add the padding
     cellProject.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 0)
```

ZoneName on cell tap:

Assuming the values presented on the cells are all on the `array_item` array, you only need to get the array object associated with the cell index and then get the value and assign it to the view controller like this, before presenting the `WorkZoneViewController`:

```
let rowItem = array_item[indexPath.row]
vc.zoneName = rowItem.zoneName
```